# dispose method info

Tags: java, swing, dispose

How do you the method 
Dispose();

when doing swing java?

does anyone have anything that could help ?

Comment: Your question has next to no information that would help formulate an answer. You need to post the context of your code and explain what you are trying to do in that context.

Answer (score 1):

To dispose the parent Window you could call:

```
new form3().setVisible(true);
JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncester(btn);
win.dispose();
```

However this program design is not a good one.

Comment: what is this for Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncester(btn);

Comment: @user3552: that's to get the top level window that holds your button.

Comment: ur suggestion doesnt work

Comment: @user3552356: try improving your question then. Giving more pertinent information and code.

Comment: @user3552356: if you are seriously in need of our help,  then consider seriously improving your question.  Please check:  [help]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
form2.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: i have tried this but it opens up both the forms multiple times

Comment: is form2 a type or an instance?